# How to execute processing task and socket communication concurrently in python 3?

Tags: python, python-3.x, sockets, python-multithreading

I have some trouble trying to understand how to use the threading module
in python 3.

Origin: I wrote a python script to do some image processing on every
frame of a camera stream in a for loop. 
Therefor I wrote some functions which are used inside the main script. The main script/loop isn´t encapsulated inside a function.

Aim: I want the main loop to run the whole time. The result of the
processing of the latest frame have to be send to a socket client only
if the client sends a request to the server socket.

My idea was to use two threads. One for the image processing and one for
the server socket which listens for a request, takes the latest image
processing result and sends it to the client socket.
I saw different tutorials how to use threading and understand the
workflow in general, but not how to use it to cope with this particular
case. So I hope for your help.

Below there is the rough structure of the origin script:

```
import cv2
import numpy
import json
import socket
from threading import Thread

def crop(image, coords):
        ...

def cont(image):
        ...

# load parameters
a = json_data["..."]

# init cam
camera = PiCamers()

# main loop
for frame in camera.capture_continuous(...):

        #######
        # some image processing
        #######

        result = (x, y, z)
```

Thank you in advance for your ideas!

Greetings

Answer (score 0):

Basically you have to create a so called ThreadPool.

In this ThreadPool function you can add the functions you want to be executed in a thread with their specific parameters. Afterwards you can start the Threadpool.

https://www.codementor.io/lance/simple-parallelism-in-python-du107klle

Here the threadPool with .map is used. There are more advanced functions that do the job. You can read the documentary of ThreadPools or search other tutorials.

Hope it helped